# Would I use mod_rewrite to direct google to the correct country specific sitemap? e.g. domain.com/sitemap.xml and domain.co.uk/sitemap.xml

Tags: mod-rewrite, dns, sitemap

We have a site with identical content for two english speaking domains.

After searching around for the best way of handling this, we opted for google's recommendation of using country specific domain names - apparently Google will serve up the correct domain based on the user's location.

Unfortunately our CMS will only serve up one sitemap.xml file - so the links in the sitemap only contain one of the country specific domains.

We've now created a sitemap.xml file for each domain (in different directories) but need a way to serve the correct sitemap based on the incoming domain.

**e.g.**

**domain.com/sitemap.xml (.com urls only) & domain.co.uk/sitemap.xml (.co.uk urls only)**

Is this a job for mod-rewrite and if so, how would you go about setting this up?

This is our first experience with mod-rewite outside of what the CMS provides and have found the documentation a bit confusing sorry - any help would be much appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Actually, maybe a 301 redirect would be the best way of handling this?

Just redirect this:

domain.co.uk/sitemap.xml

to this:

    domain.co.uk/sitemapuk/sitemap.xml

Would that be easier?

Comment: Used a redirect like this and it seems to work:

    Redirect permanent /sitemap.xml /sitemap-uk/sitemap.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use mod_rewrite for this and use HTTP_HOST as a condition, for example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml /sitemapus/sitemap.xml  [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml /sitemapuk/sitemap.xml  [L]
```

This will cause the redirect to happen on the server, so the client's browser doesn't get redirected.